# Loading image via picasso in listview in android

Tags: android, listview, picasso, image-loading

I am using code below for loading image via picasso in list view

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            tampil_semua_laporan.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{konfigurasi.TAG_TANGGAL,konfigurasi.TAG_JUDUL,konfigurasi.TAG_DESKRIPSI},
            new int[]{R.id.tanggal, R.id.judul, R.id.deskripsi});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please Help and thanks

Comment: You need to read about the learn more about adapter.

Comment: You need to extend your adapter and override getView() to made the adpater to use your desired image loader to load image. My answer here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268953/how-to-display-the-data-of-an-external-database-in-the-listview/51298768#51298768

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Picasso library with ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120238/using-picasso-library-with-listview)

Answer (score 0):

set picasso into getView method of your simpleAdapter. like below -

```
   @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // set here
       Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(image[position]) //set your image id position here
                        .transform(new RoundedCornersTransform())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                        .into(Imageview);

        return convertView;
    }
```